# Find all integer solution for 5x = 0 (mod) 6

Tags: discrete-mathematics

5x = 0 (mod 6)

I don't even know where to begin.

Ok, does 0(mod6) = 0mod6?

0/6 always give 0 so is the answer x=0?

I don't have any clue.

Comment: An answer is $0$, but note that $5\times 6 = 30 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ so $6$ is also a solution and there are many more.

Comment: Do you know what $a=b \pmod{n}$ means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that if $a \vert (bc)$ and $(a,b)=1$, then $a \vert c$.

In your case, note that $6 \vert (5x)$ and $(6,5) = 1$. Hence, $6 \vert x$ i.e. $x \equiv 0 \pmod 6$

Comment: Should the symbol be ≡ instead of =?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ 6\!:\,\ 6x,5x\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:x = 6x\!-\!5x\equiv 0,\:$ and conversely.